# Заставить компилировать один js файл при его изменении в gulp

Tags: gulp

Есть такск `watch`, который смотрит за всеми файлами js и при изменении в любом, запускает таск `js`.

Вот таск `watch`:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('assets/_js/*.js', ['js']);
});
```

Вот таск `js`:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src('assets/_js/*.js')
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/assets/js'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

При измении любого файла js (сохранении, например), запускается таск `js`, и компилируются все файлы, а также три раза перезагружается страница в браузере, что делается строкой `.pipe(browserSync.stream());` в конце таска.

Как переработать код, чтобы при изменении конкретного файла js, таск запускался конкретно для него и один единственный раз?
Создать много тасков под все файлы js - не выход.

Comment: Попробуй посмотреть [gulp-newer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newer) и [gulp-changed](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-changed)  ... скорее второй, чем первый вариант

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо! `gulp-changed` действительно решает задачу.